# where to put my header and footer tags in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import './LoginForm.css';



class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let {username, password} = this.state;
    let {isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError} = this.props;

    return (
          <header>
   <h1>Company Login</h1>
   </header>

      <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>




        <div className="form-group-collection">
          <div className="form-group">

            <label>Username/User ID:</label>
            <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})} value={username}/>
          </div>


          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} value={password}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />

  </form>
       <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
    )
  }






  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
    this.setState({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
    isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
    loginError: state.loginError
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

This is my login page i want to add header in my page.. I added it already as shown in the code...But unfortunetly error occurs after running.. Where does I put my header and footer tag in my code.. If we put it in form the code runs..But the css applied to the form is affected by adding the footer and header.. So I need the correct way to place header and footer without intrude my form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that return statement must contain a single element only and your code contains three. So basically this should work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import './LoginForm.css';

class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let { username, password } = this.state;
    let { isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <h1>Company Login</h1>
        </header>

        <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group-collection">
            <div className="form-group">

              <label>Username/User ID:</label>
              <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} value={username} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} value={password} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <input type="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>
        <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
    this.setState({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
    isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
    loginError: state.loginError
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Comment: @EdwardMish also, use linter in your editor, it should capture this kind of an issue right away.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapper inside your render function this solution should reolve your issue:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import './LoginForm.css';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        let { username, password } = this.state;
        let { isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <header>
                    <h1>Company Login</h1>
                </header>

                <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group-collection">
                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label>Username/User ID:</label>
                            <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} value={username} />
                        </div>


                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} value={password} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
                <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
            </div>
        );

        onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let { username, password } = this.state;
            this.props.login(username, password);
            this.setState({
                username: '',
                password: ''
            });
        }

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
        isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
        loginError: state.loginError
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the wrapper div you can use the [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)(https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) if using React Fiber.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <header>
      <h1>Company Login</h1>
    </header>

    <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group-collection">
        <div className="form-group">

          <label>Username/User ID:</label>
          <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} value={username} />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} value={password} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />

      <input type="submit" value="Login" />

    </form>
    <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
</React.Fragment>
```